# Adding specific country's polygon into leaflet map layer

Tags: leaflet, javascript

Currently in my project I have a base map layer taken from OpenMapStreet. On top of this I would like to have an additional layer which adds polygons of specific countries on top of the base map layer. I have a geoJson file of the world map which includes all the geometric coordinates to draw polygons for all the countries in the world and a json file, lets call it "cities.json" which looks something like this:

> [
>
> {
>    "City": "Angers",
>    "Country": "France",
>    "ISO3": "FRA",
>   },
>
> {
>     "City": "Bar-le-Duc",
>     "Country": "France",
>     "ISO3": "FRA",
>   },
>
> {
>     "City": "Agawam",
>     "Country": "United States of America",
>     "ISO3": "USA",
>   },
>
> {
>     "City": "Albany County, NY",
>     "Country": "United States of America",
>     "ISO3": "USA",
>   }
>
> ]

My objective is to check whether or not the country exists in cities.json before adding the country's polygon on to my geoJson layer for my leaflet map. So, as seen in the example, we have the country of France and the United States of America in the cities.json file, and so in the geoJson layer of my leaflet map, there will be a colored polygon over these two countries. How to achieve this outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [filter option](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson-filter) of the `L.geoJSON` object.
I assume

- a matching *"ISO3"* property in your GeoJSON
- your GeoJSON is parsed into `var borders`
- your *cities.json* is parsed into `var cities`

Define a filter function that returns `true` if the feature's *"ISO3"* property matches one of the `cities` array's object *"ISO3"* properties:

```
function filterForISO(feature) {
  for (var i = 0, len = cities.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (cities[i]["ISO3"] == feature.properties["ISO3"]) return true;
};
```

Add `borders` to the map as a `L.geoJSON` and pass that function to it's `filter` option:

```
var border_polygons = L.geoJSON(borders, {filter: filterForISO}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you @ThingumaBob. Your answer and assumptions were spot on. Sorry for the post not being too detailed as I am inexperienced. After implementing the function with my parsed data variables and passing it to L.geoJSON's filter option, only countries found in 
"cities.json" will be projected on to my leaflet map's geoJSON layer!